# Eclipse, JDT: Marker delete is not reflected in GUI after ASTRewrite

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Ok, so I have a quickfix/refactoring that deletes or changes the type of an offending field from a Java class, if the field is not present in an external DSL.

The problem is that the marker that triggered the quickfix is not removed from the GUI the first time my `IncrementalProjectBuilder`, even though the code that removes it is executed. If I execute the quickfix a second time, the same marker gets deleted again, only that now the marker also disappears in the GUI.

Interesting fact: If I step-debug the code that deletes the marker, the GUI gets updated properly.

I figure, there is something I'm missing here, as telling some component that I'm finished with the refactoring or with removing the markers.

Any hints?

Comment: BTW: I already asked a similar question on the JDT forums, but nobody answered.

Answer (score 1):

Problems View is not updated in real time (due to performance reasons) The update is run in a separate job. So when you delete the marker, it will not get reflected immediately. So when that code runs second time/stepping thru, there is a lot of chances that the update job has run